# what is wrong with pointer notaton

Tags: c++

The problem I am facing is that when I use pointer notation and run the code it displays nothing and when I use array notation it displays the desire result. I don't know what is wrong with the pointer notation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[30] = "PROGRAMMING IS FUN";
    char* ptr = str;
/*
    int count=0;

    while(ptr[count] != '\0')
    {
        ptr[count] = tolower(ptr[count]); 
        count++;
    }

    cout<<ptr<<endl; // result is displaying
*/

    while(*ptr != '\0')
    {
        *ptr = tolower(*ptr); 
         ptr++;
    }   

    cout<<ptr<<endl; // nothing is displaying also no compiler error

    // ptr[0] and ptr[1] als0 displays nothing.
}
```

Comment: Because you print ptr after all the increments and at the end it is pointing to \0

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts                                                                                 I have written ptr [ 0 ], ptr[ 1 ]  at the end but it also displays nothing. How can i display the result?

Comment: just change your cout << ptr to cout << str << Endl;

Comment: @Subhan set pointer to point back to the start of the string. `ptr[0]` doesnt mean the same as `str[0]`. You incremented the pointer until you hit the end of the string, `ptr[0]` points to `'\0'`. `ptr[1]` is outside the bounds of the strings allowed memory .

Comment: print the original string, str like  cout<<str<<endl;

Comment: The problem isn't the pointer notation, it's that your loop changes the value of ptr: `ptr++;`

Comment: Alternatively, you could also reset `ptr` to the start by placing `ptr = str;` between the loop and your output.

Comment: @Subhan : Add `std::cout << "ptr : " << ptr << std::endl;` in your while loop to understand what happens each time you do a `ptr++`.

Answer (score 5):

When the `while` loop breaks, `ptr` is pointing to the zero byte at the end of the string. That's what `while (*ptr != '\0')` does. So when you try to output `ptr`, you're outputting an empty string. Output `str` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print "str" instead of "ptr", because ptr is pointing to the end of str.

```
cout<<str<<endl;
```

However, it would be beter to do the following:

```
int len = strlen(str);
for(int i = 0; i<len; i++){
 str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}
```

Comment: It's not better, because you're now looping over the string twice. (`strlen()` loops over the whole string until it finds the `\0`. That's how it calculates the string's length.) So your version has twice the runtime cost.